# Calculate a field based on multiple columns with repeated values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a table based on a result from a temporary table but I've tried with "if" and "case" and I cannot accomplish what I need. Below is an example of the data on the temporary table:

```
Group    Category    Product          Amount    Commission  Variable
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Group 1  Wireless    Product  $10     $10.00    0.1         N
Group 1  Wireless    Product  $20     $20.00    0.1         N
Group 1  Wireless    Product  $30     $30.00    0.1         N
Group 1  Wireless    Product  $40     $40.00    0.1         N
Group 2  Gift Cards  Product  $20-50  $0.00     0.2         Y
Group 2  Gift Cards  Product  $40     $40.00    0.1         N
Group 2  Gift Cards  Product  $60     $60.00    0.1         N
Group 3  Long Dist   Product  $10     $10.00    0.1         N
Group 3  Long Dist   Product  $20     $20.00    0.1         N
Group 3  Long Dist   Product  $30     $30.00    0.5         N
```

The criteria to build the new table is below:

- The group name cannot be repeated when all the products under it have the same 
  commission and also on a calculated column I need to put the words "All denominations" , if a group name has products with different commission (it can be repeated), we need to evaluate if is a variable product or not, if variable, we need to put the product name instead of "all denominations" on the calculated column, if not variable, I need to put the amount.

Below should be the final result:

```
Group Name  Product Category    Denominations       Commission
----------------------------------------------------------------
Group 1     Wireless           All denominations    0.1
Group 2     Gift Cards         Product Name $20-50  0.2
Group 2     Gift Cards         All denominations    0.1
Group 3     Long Distance      $20.00               0.1
Group 3     Long Distance      $30.00               0.5
```

I've heard of CTE but I do not know how to use them, the final result will be used in a SSRS report

Comment: Can you add which SQL database are you using?

Comment: If you want the group name not to be repeated when all the products under it have the same commission, then try GROUP BY on Commission column. Also, can you please share your query on how you are trying to use "If" and "case"?

Comment: Hi Ary, it is an internal database that I cannot share due to the company internal policies :/

Comment: Ary means What database is it? MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, what version etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
****TRY THIS****

;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT GROUP1, CATEGORY, COUNT(1) CUSTOM_COUNT, COMMISSION 
 FROM #TBL
 GROUP BY GROUP1,COMMISSION,CATEGORY)

 SELECT DISTINCT 
 CTE.GROUP1 AS 'GROUP NAME',
 CTE.CATEGORY AS 'PRODUCT CATEGORY',
 CASE WHEN T.VARIABLE = 'Y' AND CUSTOM_COUNT=1 THEN T.PRODUCT
      WHEN T.VARIABLE = 'N' AND CUSTOM_COUNT=1 THEN AMOUNT
      ELSE 'ALL DENOMINATIONS' END  AS 'DENOMINATIONS',
CTE.COMMISSION
FROM #TBL T
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.GROUP1 = T.GROUP1 and CTE.COMMISSION = T.COMMISSION
```

'#TBL' is a temporary table I created with your data. Replace #TBL with your actual table.

Comment: Thank you Manoj , I just have an issue with that CTE. 1- When there is only product for a group name , it should be all denominations. The only moment when a row will show the amount if when 1 group name has 1 product with different commissions than the rest , when this happen the group name will be repeated 2 times . 1 row will say "All denominations" and the one with the product name with different commission will show the value.

Comment: Still your problem statement is not clear for me. As per the code above, what I consider was 1.when the variable is Y and that group's commision is different from rest then it will show Product name. 2.If the variable is N and its commission is different from rest, then it will show amount.3. If all the commission are the same then it will show "All denomination". Please give your conditions proper.

Answer (score 0):

```
select "group" as "Group Name", category as "Product Category",
    case
        when count(*) = 1 or min(variable) = 'Y' then min(product)
        else 'All denominations'
    end as "Denominations",
    commission as "Commission"
from T
group by "group", category, commission;
```

I'm seeing something like this. It should be fairly easy to translate in a report formula if you prefer to keep the logic there. By the way, I think that "variable" isn't a great name for that column though I'm not entirely sure what it means either. You can certainly write the query without relying on that data being an accurate summary of the table though.

http://rextester.com/XFJ30442

Also I would argue that Manoj's answer is unnecessarily complicated. Clearly this is accomplished with simple grouping (the CTE is not required) and that solution still involves `select distinct`, which is often a bad practice, in order to accomplish what `group by` does anyway. Plus this is probably more portable across different platforms being that CTEs are a modern feature. (There not a reason to avoid them per se, but you didn't specify either.)

Since you're essentially grouping on `commission` it would likely make sense to reverse the last two columns. As it is I'm not sure which order the rows should appear in. You'll have to decide that and handle it in the report anyway.

Comment: Thank you shawnt00 , I just have an issue with tehscript. 1- When there is only product for a group name , it should be all denominations. The only moment when a row will show the amount if when 1 group name has 1 product with different commissions than the rest , when this happen the group name will be repeated 2 times . 1 row will say "All denominations" and the one with the product name with different commission will show the value.

Comment: @Samayoa The sample output is apparently wrong for the "Long Distance" cases.  Also it should be easy for you to make minor tweaks to the `case` logic now that you've got the idea.